# Problem with the Lightbox arrows in Portfolio (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, lightbox

I am trying to modify my lightbox portfolio. Since I changed the arrows but now I need a slightly more complex modification.
Check and click on any photo: https://iconsmgmt.com/models/

What CSS code should change so that the arrows only appear when the cursor poses on the photo?

```css
.wppap-img-grp button.slick-prev, .wppap-img-grp button.slick-prev:hover, .wppap-img-grp button.slick-prev:focus {
    right: -10px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.wppap-img-grp button.slick-next, .wppap-img-grp button.slick-next:hover, .wppap-img-grp button.slick-next:focus {
    left: -10px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you written the CSS to tell it not to display? You can be better using `display:none` and `display:block` and use a transition to fade it in. - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_transition_hover.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This CSS instead of yours.

```
.wppap-img-grp .slick-arrow{display:none !important;}
.wppap-img-grp:hover .slick-arrow{display:block !important;}
```

Comment: Yeah thats sort of what I said. However you should only need `!important` if you have truly done something wrong with your code.

Comment: @Andrew because `display: none;` is not working so.

Comment: @NicoBietti Welcome don't forget to approve and upvote.